# R: Row resampling loop speed improvement

Tags: r, loops, apply, resampling

I'm subsampling rows from a dataframe with c("x","y","density") columns at a variety of c("s_size","reps"). Reps= replicates, s_size= number of rows subsampled from the whole dataframe.

```
> head(data_xyz)
   x y density
1  6 1       0
2  7 1   17600
3  8 1   11200
4 12 1   14400
5 13 1       0
6 14 1    8000



 #Subsampling###################
    subsample_loop <- function(s_size, reps, int) {
      tm1 <- system.time( #start timer
    {
      subsample_bound = data.frame()
    #Perform Subsampling of the general 
    for (s_size in seq(1,s_size,int)){
      for (reps in 1:reps) {
        subsample <- sample.df.rows(s_size, data_xyz)
         assign(paste("sample" ,"_","n", s_size, "_", "r", reps , sep=""), subsample)
        subsample_replicate <- subsample[,] #temporary variable
        subsample_replicate <- cbind(subsample, rep(s_size,(length(subsample_replicate[,1]))),
                                     rep(reps,(length(subsample_replicate[,1]))))
        subsample_bound <- rbind(subsample_bound, subsample_replicate)

      }
    }
    }) #end timer
      colnames(subsample_bound) <- c("x","y","density","s_size","reps")
    subsample_bound
    } #end function

Here's the function call:

    source("R/functions.R")
    subsample_data <- subsample_loop(s_size=206, reps=5, int=10)
```

Here's the row subsample function:

```
# Samples a number of rows in a dataframe, outputs a dataframe of the same # of columns
# df Data Frame
# N number of samples to be taken
sample.df.rows <- function (N, df, ...) 
  { 
    df[sample(nrow(df), N, replace=FALSE,...), ] 
  }
```

It's way too slow, I've tried a few times with apply functions and had no luck. I'll be doing somewhere around 1,000-10,000 replicates for each s_size from 1:250.

Let me know what you think! Thanks in advance.

=========================================================================
UPDATE EDIT: Sample data from which to sample:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/47mpo36xh7lck0t/density.csv

Joran's code in a function (in a sourced function.R file):

```
foo <- function(i,j,data){
  res <- data[sample(nrow(data),i,replace = FALSE),]
  res$s_size <- i
  res$reps <- rep(j,i)
  res
}
resampling_custom <- function(dat, s_size, int, reps) {
  ss <- rep(seq(1,s_size,by = int),each = reps)
  id <- rep(seq_len(reps),times = s_size/int)
  out <- do.call(rbind,mapply(foo,i = ss,j = id,MoreArgs = list(data = dat),SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
}
```

Calling the function

```
set.seed(2)
out <- resampling_custom(dat=retinal_xyz, s_size=206, int=5, reps=10)
```

outputs data, unfortunately with this **warning message:**

```
Warning message:
In mapply(foo, i = ss, j = id, MoreArgs = list(data = dat), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
```

Comment: If you've tried *apply functions, why not show us that code? Also, do you have hardware that would allow a parallel implementation?

Comment: I have parallel compatible hardware- how would you recommend I approach this problem?

Comment: Start with joran's answer, then see if you want further optimization from package parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put very little thought into actually optimizing this, I was just concentrating on doing something that's at least *reasonable* while matching your procedure.

Your big problem is that you are growing objects via `rbind` and `cbind`. Basically anytime you see someone write `data.frame()` or `c()` and expand that object using `rbind`, `cbind` or `c`, you can be very sure that the resulting code will essentially be the slowest possible way of doing what ever task is being attempted.

This version is around 12-13 times faster, and I'm sure you could squeeze some more out of this if you put some real thought into it:

```
s_size <- 200
int <- 10
reps <- 30

ss <- rep(seq(1,s_size,by = int),each = reps)
id <- rep(seq_len(reps),times = s_size/int)

foo <- function(i,j,data){
    res <- data[sample(nrow(data),i,replace = FALSE),]
    res$s_size <- i
    res$reps <- rep(j,i)
    res
}

out <- do.call(rbind,mapply(foo,i = ss,j = id,MoreArgs = list(data = dat),SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

The best part about R is that not only is this way, way faster, it's also way less code.

Comment: i'm getting this warning error: Warning message:
In mapply(foo, i = ss_id, j = rep_id, MoreArgs = list(data = dat),  :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter    I want to be sure that this method generates the correct data. Thanks so much joran

Comment: @user2438134 I get no warnings at all. I won't help any further unless you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @user2438134 That was very easy to debug. You should learn how to use `browser()`. Just change `times = s_size/int` to `times = ceiling(s_size/int)`.